# Hover functionality working for alert but not able to append the span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-events

Hover functionality works for showing alert,
but I am not able to show the appended text with the span tag
and don't know whats going on with it.
Providing my code below:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('.cubeCell').each(function () {
            var htmlText = $(this).attr('data-text');
            $(this).append('<div class="cubeTextStyle">' + htmlText + '</div>');
            $(this).hover(

            function () {
                //alert("123");
                $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
            },

            function () {
                $(this).find("span:last").remove();
            });
        });
    }, 600);
});


<div class="cubeCell"
     data-text="hover here"
     class="desktopContactImage cubeCell"
     data-caption="&lt;a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 14px; color: grey;' href='/Inventory/Partnumber/?ps=list' &gt;Register&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 14px; color: grey;' href='/Bom/Bom/?ps=list' &gt;Demo&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 14px; color: grey;' &gt;Reports&lt;/a&gt;"
     data-image="http://intra.defie.co/images/Desktop_icons_02.07.13/guest.png"
></div>
```

Comment: Please click the TidyUp button and follow the instructions to clean up your fiddle. It's a mess.

Comment: It does append the *** span. Check it in IE 8. I am not even seeing the hover text in Chrome. What browser do you use ?

Comment: I am using chrome browser

Comment: Can you please strip down the code to the very basic needs

Comment: If you want to increase your odds of getting an answer you should try to make it easy for people to look at your code. You fiddle is huge, and there is a lot of code in it that is not related to your question. You should try to simplify it for people to help you.

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem http://jsfiddle.net/MG5rc/1/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much (anything) about the markup and how you're achieving the spinning box but I wonder if you're trying to show the text next to cubeStyleText as you're appending the span to the same place on hover but instead it's showing up behind the box if that's the case, instead of

```
$(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
```

use this

```
$(this).children(".cubeTextStyle").append($("<span> ***</span>"));
```

That seems to fix the positioning issues if that's what it is.